# Compiling a directive results in error: $apply already in progress

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This seems pretty simple.

In Angular JS, I'm trying to compile a directive when the user clicks a link on the page. To do this, I have an ng-click handler.

```
<a ng-switch-when="grade" id="{{ item.gb_class_id }}" ng-click="showHWClick(item.gb_class_id, item.period_id, item.student_id)" href="">{{ item.grade }}</a>
```

... and inside my controller, I define the ng-click function:

```
$scope.showHWClick = function(classId) {

        $('#' + classId).parent().parent('.grade-row').after($compile('<tr><td class="homework-row" colspan="9"><progress-report /></td></tr>')($scope));

    }
```

And here's my directive:

```
.directive('progressReport', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'Content/app/dashboard/progressreport.html'
    }
});
```

So really, I'm just compiling a template when the user clicks a link. The problem is, this returns the following error messages:

> `Error: $apply already in progress
>       at Error (<anonymous>)
>       at beginPhase (http://localhost:81/content/lib/angular/angular.js:8334:15)
>       at Object.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:81/content/lib/angular/angular.js:8136:11)
>       at Object.$delegate.__proto__.$apply (http://localhost:81/#/:855:30)
>       at done (http://localhost:81/content/lib/angular/angular.js:9170:20)
>       at completeRequest (http://localhost:81/content/lib/angular/angular.js:9333:7)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (http://localhost:81/content/lib/angular/angular.js:9303:11)
>       at http://localhost:81/content/lib/angular/angular.js:9312:11
>       at sendReq (http://localhost:81/content/lib/angular/angular.js:9146:9)
>       at $http (http://localhost:81/content/lib/angular/angular.js:8937:17)`
>
> `Error: Failed to load template: Content/app/dashboard/progressreport.html
>       at Error (<anonymous>)
>       at http://localhost:81/content/lib/angular/angular.js:4549:17
>       at http://localhost:81/content/lib/angular/angular.js:8957:11
>       at wrappedErrback (http://localhost:81/content/lib/angular/angular.js:6855:57)
>       at http://localhost:81/content/lib/angular/angular.js:6931:53
>       at Object.Scope.$eval (http://localhost:81/content/lib/angular/angular.js:8057:28)
>       at Object.Scope.$digest (http://localhost:81/content/lib/angular/angular.js:7922:25)
>       at Object.$delegate.__proto__.$digest (http://localhost:81/#/:844:31)
>       at Object.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:81/content/lib/angular/angular.js:8143:24)
>       at Object.$delegate.__proto__.$apply (http://localhost:81/#/:855:30)`

The failed to load template error is strange, because I've quadruple checked the location of the template and it's correct. But I assume the error is a result of the first error message.

Does anyone know what's wrong? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: [Here's the Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YCIfyocAsLKQwkz5yzz2?p=preview)

EDIT 2: I'm using Angular 1.0.7.

Comment: What version of angular are you using?

Comment: can you post a plnkr code sample?

Comment: You're using a jQuery selector, but I don't see jQuery in your Plunker. Can you verify that it is in your project? If there is no element selected, that would cause the problem you are having.

Comment: Your Plunker is empty. Wrong URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing DOM manipulation outside of your directive to begin with.  Rather than modifying the DOM, your `showHWClick` function should likely modify some property or object on the scope.  Your templates would then be bound to that property and update like any other angular template.

This is all covered at http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/.

If I had to guess at what you're trying to accomplish, you might want to take a look at the `ngIf` directive that was introduced in 1.1.5 to conditionally add a piece of DOM ( not just show/hide it ).

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the click event can you try with below code:

```
$scope.showHWClick = function(classId) {
        $timeout(function(){
            if (!$scope.$$phase) {
                $('#' + classId).parent().parent('.grade-row').after($compile('<tr><td class="homework-row" colspan="9"><progress-report /></td></tr>')($scope));
            }
        }, 500, false);

    }
```

Comment: You can also use 0 as delay value.

Comment: $timeout should not be used if not really required. It would dirty check all the bindings and would slow down the template.